# (111) Connection refused - Apache Tomcat on port 8080 - External

Tags: port-forwarding, tomcat

I just got my webpage running yesterday, but some how when i tried to connect external i get a  (111) Connection refused. I have port forwarding on 8080, and it is working perfectly internally.

I have tried change the port to 80, 8080, 8081, 443 but with out luck. I use a Netgear router and there are no port blocking on it.

I can connect to my NAS externally by portforwarding.

Comment: did you restart apache in between changing ports? Also, see if there's a DMZ mode and put your system in it to check if it works then. Also, what is the external port you are using?

Comment: Apache are running on my computer through Eclipse. I have tried restart, with no help. I tried to use the DMZ and set the IP to my computers IP. I am using port 8080. I tried to use a different port-forwarding to 443, but that is not working at all.

Comment: Picture of what can be the problem: [link](http://i55.tinypic.com/s2dzr4.jpg)

Comment: why is apache running through eclipise? also, looks like port 8080 is used by the router. test it with an arbitrary port first - i like 9180

Comment: I have tried port "9180" but with out luck. I use Eclipse to programm, in i start the stop the server through the program. I have tried with another computer and go to external-ip:8080/hello.jsp and it works when we are on same router. It is only externel i get problems.

Comment: What OS is this?  Can you post a ```netstat -pant``` if linux, or ```netstat -anbp tcp``` if Windows.  Run with root or administrative privleges repectively, and ensure apache is running at the time.

Comment: It is Mac OS Lion :(